# Generic observer pattern in C++

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, observer-pattern

In many cases in my application i need class A to register itself as a listener on class B to receive notification when something happens. In every case i define a separate interface B implements and A can call do. So for example, A will have the following method:

```
void registerSomeEventListener(SomeEventListener l);
```

Also, in many cases, B will need to support multiple listeners so i reimplement the registration and notifyAll logic.

One generic way i know is to have some EventListener (implement by A) and EventNotifier (implement by B) classes. In this case each event is identified by a string and A implements the method:

```
void eventNotified(string eventType);
```

I think this is not a good solution. It will result in many if-else statements in case A listens to several events and might result in bugs when event names are changed only in the listener or the notifier.

I wonder what is the correct way to implement the observer pattern in C++?

Comment: I [wrote something about this](http://juanchopanzacpp.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/simple-observer-pattern-implementation-c11/) a while back. My "listeners" are just callable entities. I'm not sure if it fits your use-case exactly, but it might be worth looking at.

Comment: There is no right or wrong way.  There are dozens of ways implemented for various reasons.  The most common is to use virtual functions, and have listeners derive from this base interface.  But it has limitations.  You can also store individual class instance and method names, so that only those classes registered receive callbacks.  If your into using boost then they have some good utility for handling this.  If you'd rather write your own, then you'd want to look into templates, and who to define a pointer to a class method..

Comment: @Dan So what you are saying is that the most common way is the non-generic way? Simply create a specific listener type for every scenario and make class A derive from it and implement its functions?

Comment: I would not say that, but the more generic you get, the less performant it becomes.  You can't have a generic pointer to a class instance.  Not unless they all derive from the same base, in which case the method pointer of that class must be defined in the base class.  If however you're not concerned with performance, then you can create a thunking layer from a base class which has a virtual Invoke, which proxies the Specific Class and method function bound.  But a virtual call typically results in a cache miss.  You can usually live with that.

Comment: If you need something more performant, IE: getting called hundreds of times per frame, then you should use a more specific callback mechanism..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [boost::signals2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/signals2.html). It provides a generic mechanism to define "signals" where other objects can register. The signal owner can then notify observers by "firing" the signal. Instead of register-methods, the subject defines signals as members which then keep track of connected observers and notify them when initiated. The signals are statically typed and accept every function with the matching signature. This has the advantage that there is no need for inheritance and thus a weaker coupling than the traditional observer inheritance hierarchy.

```
class Subject {
public:
    void setData(int x) {
         data_ = x;
         dataChanged(x);
     }

     boost::signals2<void (int)> dataChanged;

private:
    int data_;
};

class Observer {
public:
    Observer(Subject& s) {
        c_ = s.dataChanged.connect([&](int x) {this->processData(x);});
    }

    ~Observer() {
        c_.disconnect();
    }

private:
    void processData(int x) {
        std::cout << "Updated: " << x << std::endl;
    }

    boost::signals2::connection c_;
};

int main() {
    Subject s;

    Observer o1(s);
    Observer o2(s);

    s.setData(42);

    return 0;
}
```

In this example, the subject holds some int data and notifies all registered observers when the data is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a generic event fireing object:

```
class base_invoke {
public:
    virtual ~base_invoke () {};

    virtual void Invoke() = 0;
}
```

But you want to fire events on different types of objects, so you derive from base:

```
template<class C>
class methodWrapper : public base_invoke {

public:
typedef void (C::*pfMethodWrapperArgs0)();

    C *             mInstance;
    pfMethodWrapperArgs0 mMethod;

public:
    methodWrapper(C * instance, pfMethodWrapperArgs0 meth) 
    : mInstance(instance) 
{
        mMethod = meth;
    }

    virtual void Invoke () {
        (mInstance->*mMethod)();
    }
}
```

Now if you create a wrapper for a collection of pointers to base_invoke you can call each fireing object and signal whichever method on whichever class you'd like.

You can also turn this collection class into a factory for the fireing objects.  to simplyfy the work.

```
class Event {

protected:
    Collection<base_invoke *> mObservers;

public:

    // class method observers
    template<class C>
    void Add (C * classInstance, typename methodWrapper<C>::pfMethodWrapperArgs0 meth) {
        methodWrapper<C> * mw = NEW(methodWrapper<C>)(classInstance, meth);
        mObservers.Add(ObserverEntry(key, mw));
    }

    void Invoke () {
        int count = mObservers.Count();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            mObservers[i]->Invoke();
        }
    }
};
```

And your done with the hard work.  Add an Event object anyplace you want listeners to subscribe.  You'll probably want to expand this to allow removal of listeners, and perhaps to take a few function parameters but the core is pretty much the same.

Comment: This has the benefit of allowing you to call a different method for each event that gets fired.  The if else you were worried about gets performed when you register for the proper event..

Comment: Sorry, I tried to list the full source but the web site has a 30000 character limit. Hope this helps.